# Silverlight resource constructor always return to internal

Tags: c#, silverlight, resources, resx

When I modify my resource file (`.resx`) add text or modify, the constructor of my resource always go to internal and after that, when I run my silverlight I have an error in my binding XAML.

Is there a way to avoid this scenario? I need to go in the designer of my resource and put the constructor to public to solve the problem

I use my resource like this in my xaml file

```xml
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <resources:LibraryItemDetailsView x:Key="LibraryItemDetailsViewResources"></resources:LibraryItemDetailsView>
    </UserControl.Resources>


<TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=FileSelectedText3, Source={StaticResource LibraryItemDetailsViewResources}}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, it's annoying...

Comment: I have done [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16174350/385995) in WPF, should work for Silverlight as well.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this without code changes is as below. Worked well for me.

http://guysmithferrier.com/post/2010/09/PublicResourceCodeGenerator-now-works-with-Visual-Studio-2010.aspx

Comment: This is the best answer. Install the exe and set the Custom Tool property of your resource file to "PublicResourceCodeGenerator".

Answer (score 3):

You can create a public class that exposes the resources through a property:

```
public class StringsWrapper
{
    private static LibraryItemDetailsView _view = null;

    public LibraryItemDetailsView View
    {
        get
        {
            if (_view == null)
            {
                _view = new LibraryItemDetailsView();
            }
            return _view;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML you can access your resource:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <StringsWrapper x:Key="LibraryItemDetailsViewResources"></StringsWrapper>
</UserControl.Resources>


<TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=View.FileSelectedText3, Source={StaticResource LibraryItemDetailsViewResources}}"></TextBlock>
```

This way the resx constructor can be internal!

Answer (score 1):

Well, what I did was to add a command line utility to pre-build event of each Silverlight project that replaces each `internal` `string` with `public` :)

You can edit pre-build and post-build events by: Right-clicking on a project -> `Properties` -> `Build Events`.

I used a utility called [RXFIND](http://rxfind.codeplex.com/releases/view/624), it's free and can replace a string within selected files using a `RegEx` regular expression.

Here's the command line I'm using:

```
"$(SolutionDir)ThirdParty\rxfind\rxfind.exe" "$(ProjectDir)Resources\*.Designer.cs" "/P:internal " "/R:public " /Q /B:2
```

Please note, that all my resources are located under Resource directory within each project and the command line utility resides in `\ThirdParty\rxfind` directory

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same error. To solve the problem I just created a `public class` that inherits from the class representing the resources file, knowing that it must also be public class this is my exep:

```
public class TrackResourceWrapper : TrackResource
{
}
```

with:
`TrackResourceWrapper` is inheriting class
`TrackResource` is the class which is located in the code resource file behind (public class)

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

1. Add a new class that inherits from the resource class
2. In the App.xaml file, modify the resource class which you created

Done!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you shouldn't be instantiating the class yourself. You should instead always use `ConsoleApplication1.Resource1.ResourceManager` which itself instantiates the class for you.

Here, `ConsoleApplication1` is the name of your assembly and `Resource1` the name of your resource file.

Comment: Can you give me an example with binding ?

Comment: The ResourceManager that you mention doesn't expose the string variables so it won't be bindable. You'd have to use a GetX method to get any values from it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a macro to do this for me for each file I edit. I still have to remember to run it, but it's a lot quicker. Please see [my post](http://wblo.gs/cO9).