# Databind Resource File in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

For localization I'm using the Resource-file (.resx files) functionality in .NET, but I'm wondering if there's a smart way to databind the various localization properties directly in XAML?

The resource file only seems to expose static properties, which I can't figure out how to bind from a viewmodel, or other resource dictionary.

Also, if it's possible, I'd like it to work at design-time with Expression Blend.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is how I do it.

WPF:

1. Create a resource file and in the same assembly create a class that has a public constructor.  Make sure the resource file is marked public.
2. In your xaml file - add a reference to this location in the namespaces

   `xmlns:res="clr-namespace:MyProject.StringResources"`
3. For your text property use the following binding

   `TextProperty="{x:Static res:ResourceFileName.ResourceKey}"`

Silverlight:

1. Follow steps 1 & 2 above and then add the resource file as a Resource in either your user control or in an application level resource:

   `<res:ResourceFileName x:Key="resourcesLabels"/>`
2. For your text property use the following binding:

   `TextProperty="{Binding ResourceKey, Source={StaticResource resourceLabels}}"`

Comment: That seems to work for WPF. However, for Silverlight `x:Static` doesn't seem to be supported. Any ideas on how to handle that?

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to what Geek proposed, but even a bit easier I think:

Create a class in the same assembly, which inherits the resources file and exposes a public constructor, then use this class instead.

```
public class ResourcesProxy : Properties.Resources
{
    /// <summary>
    /// resolves the problem of internal constructor in resources.designer.cs
    /// in conjunction with xaml usage
    /// </summary>
    public ResourcesProxy() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you would be limited to a single resources file here.

Comment: You add one proxy class per resx file. For WPF the {x:Static ...} is easiest.