# Determine Local Uri (Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() returns null)

Tags: c#

I have a project-folder called TestA, then a folder in it called TestB and in that one a folder with the name TestC. In TestC is an image (Image.png) and i want to know how to get that uri.

I need to call a function and give the Uri to the function

I already tried many things like:

```
Class.Function(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TestB/TestC/Image.png"));
```

But I always get this Exception:

`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() returns null.`

I am pretty sure, that this part isn´t correct: "pack://application:,,,/TestB/TestC/Image.png"

Thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: Does this happen when you are running a unit test? When you do that `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` will return null.

Comment: It happens in the function Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409819/pack-uri-to-image-embedded-in-a-resx-file

Comment: I already found that post, but what how would be the syntax for the Uri in my example then? new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TestA;component/TestB/TestC/images.png")?

Comment: Okay... I think the problem is, that the main application is no wpf application :/

Answer (score 0):

When your application is not a WPF application, like when you're developing a plugin for a non managed application, `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` returns `null` because there is no entry assembly.

So WPF is not able to reconstitute the full path of the resource. You need to help him by giving him the name of the assembly like this:

```
pack://application:,,,/<AssemblyName>;component/TestC/Image.png
```

where `<AssemblyName>` is the name of the assembly where the resource can be found.