# WPF Accessing image path from shared project

Tags: c#, wpf, shared-project

I have a WPF application (Project A) in which i have a Resource Dictionary file Global.xaml. In this file i am refering

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="Test" UriSource="..\Images\Test.png">
```

The above line references the image from the below path

```
pack://application:,,,/Assembly of Project A;component/Images/Test.png
```

Now i am moving the image to a Shared project (Shared Project A) and is referenced in Project A. So what would be UriSource?

I tried giving Assembly of Shared Project A;component/Images/Test.png

but it is not taking the image from shared project.

Comment: Related question in case you run into trouble with this: [*Pack URI to image embedded in a resx file*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16409819/109702)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

**General:**

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/<ReferencedAssemblyName>;component/<PathInReferencedAssembly>"
```

**In your case:**

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/SharedProjectA;component/Images/Test.png"
```

Also make sure the `Build-Action` is `Resource` for all of your Images and the project is built successfully.

Comment: This solution does not work for me, it throws `FileNotFoundException` because it is trying to find `SharedProjectA` assembly, but such assembly does not exist because shared projects do not create own assemblies. I am playing with almost empty solution and I have a strange problem: I have an image in folder `SharedProject/Images/image.png`. When I reference it as `/Images/image.png` it correctly shows up in designer, but not in runtime. On the other hand when I reference it without path as `image.png`, it does not show in designer, but works in runtime :(

Comment: Yep, shared project does not produce an assembly. I was able to load picture after using main assembly name, not shared one: `Source="pack://application:,,,/MyLibraryAssemblyName;component/Images/Test.png"`